# PHP strpos is not finding needle

Tags: php, csv, strpos

I've problem with `strpos()`, is not returning properly position, but always false.

```
class generate
{
        function test()
        {
            $array1 = file_get_contents('file.csv'); //get content of file
            $array1 = explode(PHP_EOL, $array1); //each row in table
            foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
            {
               $array2 = preg_split("/[\t]/", $value); //to split each row into separate arrays fields
            }
            foreach($array2 as $array3)
            {
               $array3[2] = '[TRIGGER] ...';
               var_dump(strpos($array3[2], 'TRIGGER'));
            }
        }
 }
 $test = new generate();
 $test->test();
```

In place of three dots in `$array3[2]` there is a different content. I've check and content of `$array3[2]` is ok, but it still don't want to find my needle in string. The `$array` takes data from csv file using `file_get_contents();`. Any advices?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything defined as `$array`. And https://eval.in/501628

Comment: As Sougata said, there is no `$array` defined, you might mean `... strpos($array3[2], ...`

Comment: Yes ofcourse you've right, in code I've got properly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will answer myself, the PHP file was coded in UTF-8, when I change to UTF-8 CSV file, everything start to work properly.

Thanks! :)